# javascript works in console but not on page even after adding $(document).ready(function ()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I just can't get this to work. It works fine in the console of Google Chrome. I added `$(document).ready(function ()`. Still no luck. Any help is greatly appreciated. update: I'm trying to get the value of the first cell when the row is selected on a dynamically created html table

Script

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("VisitList")',
        method: 'post',
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: 'application/json;charset=utf-8',
        data: "{id: 112601}",
        success: function (data) {
            //alert("success");
            $('#divData').removeClass('hidden');
            $('#tblBody').empty();
            $.each(data, function (index, value) {
                var row = $('<tr><td>' + value.JobID + '</td><td>'
                    + value.VisitID + '</td><td>'
                    + value.VisitDate + '</td><td>'
                    + value.VisitInfo + '</td><td>'
                    + value.Engineer + '</td></tr>');
                $('#tblData').append(row);
            });
        },
        error: function (xhr) {
            alert(xhr.responseText);

        }
    });

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#tblBody tr").click(function (rowElement) {
            //alert("hello");
            var value = $(this).find('td:first').html();
            alert(value);
        })
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Where are you including this script tag  ? try including it at the last just before body closing tag

Comment: Could you more explain what you are trying to do?

Comment: Are you getting the alert when you uncomment it or not  ?

Comment: This isn't flagged jQuery but is jQuery, so did you include it? We need some more context, where did you place your scripts? How did you get it to work then?

Comment: @NanditaAroraSharma  Placing the scripts just before the body closing tag is indeed a good idea, but in this case `$(document).ready(` will have the same effect.

Comment: You mention that the table is dynamicly generated. Is the `$("#tblBody tr")` in the document when you bind the click event? If not, the click event will not work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Event binding on dynamically created elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)

Comment: Thanks for all the comments. @NanditaAroraSharma I included it after the defining the table.

Comment: @Jeppsen It is inside the function

Comment: try nikhil Aggarwal’s answer then .. it should work

Comment: @NanditaAroraSharma Yes nikhil answer worked

Comment: @CBroe sorry buddy. this is not a duplicate. I believe my question was different

Comment: Unless the elements you are trying to select with `#tblBody tr` are present in the document at that point already, this is a duplicate. And since you are clearing your table with `$('#tblBody').empty()` before you add new table rows, that absolutely is the case here. That you have not _understood_ it yet, doesn’t make it less of a duplicate. Even the answer here that you just accepted tells basically the exact same thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you are adding rows dynamically, you need to use [jQuery.on](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

```
 $("#tblBody").on("click", "tr", function (rowElement) {
     var value = $(this).find('td:first').html();
     alert(value);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably forgot to add a jQuery to the head of your HTML. See the example:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  alert("Hello World!");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

What is the error?

Try putting this at the start of that Script:

```
console.log($().jquery);
```

It should print out the jQuery version so you know jQ is available at that point.

Also, the document might be ready but could it be that you add elements to it later dynamically?

```
 $("#tblBody tr")
```

Maybe target for this is missing? Not loaded or you targeted poorly?

In any case, if above does not fix the problem, do include error, relevant HTML structure and any additional code that might change HTML in the question to make it a complete one.

PRO TIP: Questions that have plunker or similar available are solved way faster and do attract more people.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `.on` click event on `document` something like this:

```
$(document).on('click', '#tblBody tr', function () {
    var value = $(this).find('td:first').text();
    alert(value);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you add any data dynamically at that time you should use jquery .on() method.Like this:

```
    $("#tblBody").on("click", "tr", function (rowElement) {
     var value = $(this).find('td:first').html();
     alert(value);
   });
```